# How can I run SQL commands against dockerized SQL Server via docker-compose?

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have a SQL Server running inside a Docker container. It is setup via docker-compose file and tied to my .NET Core API:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

   appdb:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
      container_name: ${SQL_SERVER_CONTAINER_NAME}
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
         - "${SQL_SERVER_HOST_PORT}:1433"
      environment:
         SA_PASSWORD: ${SQL_SERVER_USER_PASSWORD}
         ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      volumes:
         - ./../../.microsoft/data:/var/opt/mssql/data
         - ./../../.microsoft/log:/var/opt/mssql/log
         - ./../../.microsoft/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets

   demoapi.website:
      image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}demoapiwebsite
      build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: DemoAPI.Website/Dockerfile
      container_name: ${APP_NAME}-app
      environment:
         - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
         - "ConnectionStrings__AppConnectionString=Server=${SQL_SERVER_CONTAINER_NAME},${SQL_SERVER_HOST_PORT}; Initial Catalog=${APP_NAME};User ID=${SQL_SERVER_USER_ID};Password=${SQL_SERVER_USER_PASSWORD}"
      depends_on:
         - appdb
      ports:
         - "8000:80"
```

I also have a bunch of SQL script files inside my .NET Core API project. These scripts basically define how to create and seed the database when the project is started.

What I would like to do is to execute these scripts somehow once the dockerized SQL Server is up and running. Is it possible to do this via the docker-compose file?

I see a lot of tutorials which use the actual .NET app and do this during the app start up with EF migrations, but I would prefer to get this done via docker-compose, if possible?

Comment: You can configure a script to run  after SQL Server mounts all online DB's. This may or may not be helpful -> https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/10/16/sql-server-configure-stored-procedure-run-server-startup-simple-tutorial/

Comment: Im not sure about this way why dont you create a shell script for sql queries  and execute it via docker compose file?

Comment: @vgeorge That link does not work for me...

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_script_unix_sql.htm